# How can I do a Karate matcher for "any array item starts with" on a String array?

Tags: karate

Let's say I have a "workflow result" equal to:

```
["START","Success : <0_4726310526.1228950033456.WEBSERVICES@random>","END"]
```

If I were to write a Karate matcher to verify that any item in that list "starts with the sub-string 'Success'",  then how would I write the matcher?

This is what I tried and I can't get it to work:

```
* def starts_with = function(x){ return x.startsWith('Success') }
* match result_arr contains any ["# starts_with(_)"]
```

Couldn't find the answer in the documentation for Karate.

Comment: `Couldn't find the answer in the documentation for Karate.` yes the docs suck. everyone says that.

Comment: The docs are way better than some.   But, there are a few edge cases, like this one, that are not directly documented.   I don't think it deserves a "docs suck" though.

Comment: the docs will never cover all edge cases. that's what stack overflow is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def response = ["START","Success : <0_4726310526.1228950033456.WEBSERVICES@random>","END"]
* def fun = function(x){ return x.startsWith('Success') }
* def temp = karate.filter(response, fun)
* assert temp.length > 0
```